# HTACCESS deixa de funcionar corretamente na troca de ambiente

Tags: htaccess, url-rewrite, url-amigável

Tenho que fazer uma migração de um site de uma hospedagem de ***novato*** para uma hospedagem de servidor dedicado e o meu htaccess simplesmente resolveu deixar de responder as urls enviando assim a url para a página de erro.

Ele até monta a url conforme pode ser observado [**aqui**](http://colnag.com.br) passando o mouse em cima dos imóveis mas ao clicar na mesma vai para uma ***página de erro*** que é a home do site.

Estou tentando a dias resolver o problema mas não consigo. Nos links abaixo, pode ser observado as configurações dos servidor *antigo* e *novo* e o arquivo *htaccess* em questão.

***Ambiente antigo***

```
http://www.colnaghi.com.br/info.php
```

***Ambiente novo***

```
http://www.colnag.com.br/info.php
```

***.htaccess***

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php

# AddHandler php56-script .php
# suPHP_ConfigPath /home/colnag/

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]\-]+)=([0-9-]+)$ http://colnag.com.br/imovel_detalhe?cod_consulta=$2 [P]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

> Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver?

Não consegui visualizar a versão do Apache na ***hospedagem antiga***.